# musl-gcc not working

Tags: compiling, gcc

I have linux installed in armv6 android phone in chrooted environment.

I have installed [musl-libc](http://www.musl-libc.org/) from source for building static binary for android.
Here are the commands, I ran for building & installing in debian

```
./configure --disable-shared 
make
make install
```

Here is config.mak  ::

```
# This version of config.mak was generated by:
# ./configure --disable-shared
# Any changes made here will be lost if configure is re-run
ARCH = arm
SUBARCH =
ASMSUBARCH = el
prefix = /usr/local/musl
exec_prefix = $(prefix)
bindir = $(exec_prefix)/bin
libdir = $(prefix)/lib
includedir = $(prefix)/include
syslibdir = /lib
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Os -pipe -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-unwind-tables -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -Wa,--noexecstack -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -$
CFLAGS_C99FSE = -std=c99 -nostdinc -ffreestanding -fexcess-precision=standard -frounding-math
CFLAGS_MEMOPS = -fno-tree-loop-distribute-patterns
CPPFLAGS =
LDFLAGS = -Wl,--hash-style=both
CROSS_COMPILE =
LIBCC = -lgcc -lgcc_eh
OPTIMIZE_GLOBS = internal/*.c malloc/*.c string/*.c
SHARED_LIBS =
```

It got built & installed fine without any errors.

But when I check for installation .

```
cat > hello.c <<EOF
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{   printf("hello, world!\n");
return 0;
}
EOF
/usr/local/musl/bin/musl-gcc hello.c
./a.out
```

It shows this error ::

```
/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabi/4.6/libgcc.a(_dvmd_lnx.o): In function     `__aeabi_ldiv0':
(.text+0x8): undefined reference to `raise'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What's wrong with musl installation ?

Answer (score 1):

Got following reply from musl support team.

```
If you add -v, you should see
.. --start-group -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lc --end-group ..

which means all dependencies between libgcc and libc are resolved. I think gcc does not do the --start-group/--end-group without  explicit -static, so only musl-gcc -static hello.c would work.


raise is in libc, referenced from libgcc
__aebi_ldiv0 is in libgcc, referenced from libc with static linking, undefined symbol resolution happens in the order the libraries are listed on the command line (so you need -lgcc -lc -lgcc -lc or the --*-group linker flags to resolve circular deps)
```

So I had to use -static flag while compiling.